# GetFileAttributes() function doesn't work with a relative path to a folder

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I have a Visula C++ console application in MS VS 2013 where I'm checking the existence of folder on a hard drive. I use GetFileAttributes() function for it in the following way:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     string folderPath = argv[1];

     if (GetFileAttributes(folderPath.c_str()) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
     {
          // Do something here
     }
     else
     {
          // Also do something here
     }

     return 0;
}
```

But the result of GetFileAttributes() is equal to FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY (0x10) only if I set (in command line arguments) a fully qualified path to folder. For example: "*M:\MS_VS2013_Projects\WordsCounter\Debug\TextFiles_to_Test*" where "M" is a hard drive name.
But if I try to set (in command line arguments) a relative path for example: "*TextFiles_to_Test*" or "*M:TextFiles_to_Test*" or "*\TextFiles_to_Test*" or "*.\TextFiles_to_Test*" then GetFileAttributes() returns the wrong result == 4294967295. How can I achieve the correct resuli (0x10) in case of relative path to folder? I'll be very thankful for your help.

Comment: if I do the following:   if ((GetFileAttributes(folderPath.c_str()) & 0x10) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) it doesn't help because in that case the "if-statement" is satisfied even in the case of non-existent folders.

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the current working directory or drive, not the app directory. There's one CWD per process, but Windows also stores the working directory on each drive in hidden environment variables (e.g. `=C:`).

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to Windows XP. I made some tests on Windows 7. It doesn't work with relative paths, and also doesn't work with "reparse points". For instance, if you use localized versions of a folder, it won't work.

Ex: on a French Windows OS, only the 1st of the following calls will succeed.

```
DWORD dwAttr1 = ::GetFileAttributesW(L"C:\\Program Files");
DWORD dwAttr2 = ::GetFileAttributesW(L"Program Files"); //relative folder
DWORD dwAttr3 = ::GetFileAttributesW(L"C:\\Programmes"); //NTFS Junction point
DWORD dwAttr4 = ::GetFileAttributesW(L"Programmes");
```